# Comment transposer l'emploi des « crickets » signifiant le silence ou l'absence de communication ?

Tags: anglais, comparaison-de-langues, zoologie, onomatopées

> "I asked him where things stand on the contract. All I heard was....
> (crickets)." ([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=*crickets*))
>  "She promised to give me a progress report last week.
> Since then --- *crickets* "([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=*crickets*))

On a une évolution de cette référence au seul son de ces insectes à la campagne pour signifier éventuellement le *silence* ou l'*absence de communication* [en langue anglaise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-were-watching-crickets-silence). Et on finit avec un emploi entièrement décontextualisé, seul :

> “Woolgathering,” I said, eyeing Dr. Takemago for her response.
> **Crickets**. [...] (Merriam-Webster, [*Words We're Watching: 'Crickets' -
> A word for the sound of silence*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-were-watching-crickets-silence))

A-t-on un moyen équivalent en français ou comment transposerait-on ces *crickets* ; est-ce généralement employé entre parenthèses ou autrement ?

Comment: Ah! c'est donc une référence aux criquets/grillons et non à un sport typiquement anglais!

Comment: @XouDo Tu pourrais trouver le très britannique et vieux _not cricket_ mais ce serait au singulier. Je n'ai jamais entendu ça. En Amérique du Nord il est assez rare d'évoquer le nom de ce sport-là.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En restant autour des insectes :

> *On entendrait une mouche voler*

Sinon :

> Silence radio

> Un ange passe…

Answer (score 5):

Pour compléter, on pourrait aussi avoir :

> Il y eut un blanc (dans la conversation)

> Un silence assourdissant lui répondit

S'agissant de la deuxième phrase (aucune nouvelle), outre *Silence radio*, on peut dire :

> Depuis, rien!